# How can I solve 'TypeError: userId is not a function' in my unban command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create a **unban command** for my bot, but every time I want to test the command (`!unban <userId>`) I'm not getting the expected result. Instead, I'm getting an **error** as shown down below.

This is my **code**:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    usage: '%unban <userId> <reason>',
    description: 'To unban someone',

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return;
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply(`You do not have permission to unban`);
        let userId = args[0];
        if (!userId) return message.reply(`Please state a user ID to unban`);
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) reason = "No reason mentioned";
        if (userId === message.author.id) return message.reply(`You can not unban yourself`);

        let bans = await message.guild.fetchBans();
        if (bans.has(userId)) {
            message.guild.members.unban(userId({ reason }))
            message.channel.send(`Successfully unbanned **${userId}**`);
        } else {
            message.reply(`Provided ID is invalid or isn't a banned member`)
        }
    }
}
```

Here the **error** I'm getting:

```
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
(node:23184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: userId is not a function        
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\commands\unban.js:19:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:23184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of 
an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that 
are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: `message.guild.members.unban(userId({ reason }))` should be `message.guild.members.unban(userId, reason)`, since `userId` isn't a function. If that doesn't fix your problem please update your question!

Comment: Error is self explanatory, you try calling `userId` as a function when it's a property. In the line `message.guild.members.unban(userId({ reason }))` did you mean?`message.guild.members.unban(userId, { reason })`.    Edit: I've just viewed the docs [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=unban) and see that the reason should be passed as a parameter not an option

Comment: ahhh yep that worked thanks

Comment: @Mitchell Maybe you should post this as an actual answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild.members.unban(userId({ reason }))` should be `message.guild.members.unban(userId, reason)`, since userId isn't a function.